# Any date entry in the text will be captured in agenda view

Tags: org-mode

I guess this is best explained by screenshots.
I have one entry like this:
[image]

then I run `M-x org-agenda RET a RET` and I get something like this:
[image]

Problem is, I do not want this timestamp to show up in my agenda as it's the content under the heading **Problems and solutions**, instead of a Deadline or Scheduled time.

I've googled for a few hours but amazingly couldn't get any helpful information.

thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I found [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46388/time-in-org-heading-is-read-as-timestamp-by-org-agenda) and tried the solution (set `org-agenda-search-headline-for-time` provided anyway but had no luck. Also tried searching for something like **-for-time** as suggested but it didn't give me any more than `org-agenda-search-headline-for-time`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `inactive` timestamps, delineated with `[]` rather than `<>`: `[2020-02-08]` instead of `<2020-02-08>`. See the [Timestamps](https://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html#Timestamps) section of the [Dates and Times](https://orgmode.org/manual/Dates-and-Times.html#Dates-and-Times) chapter in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Just when I was going to give up, I came across this option in the source code:

`org-agenda-skip-additional-timestamps-same-entry nil`

> "When nil, multiple same-day timestamps in entry make multiple
>   agenda lines. When non-nil, after the search for timestamps has
>   matched once in an entry, the rest of the entry will not be searched."
>   :group 'org-agenda-skip   :type 'boolean)

This should roughly solve the problem but I'm looking for something that will only include Deadline and Scheduled times.

Comment: See @mankoff's answer: you should be using inactive timestamps for this: `[2020-02-08]` instead of active ones like `<2020-02-08>`.

Comment: @NickD couldn't believe i didn't see that.

Comment: You are now an honorary member of the "I couldn't believe I didn't see that" club: it's got about 8 billion members. Welcome to the club :-)

Comment: @NickD Feels good.